# Ajax response stop the typing in div content editable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have  row column structue in table .I update the content  every two second  as i need to display changes on another browser at same time.Right now I update the content through ajax and fill response in outer div but when response fill I am not able to enter new content in column  as ajax response stop the typing for short while and mouse cursor comes very first column. how we can fix it 
my format  like this

It not excel sheet but just like excel sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min_1.7.2.js"></script>

<!--jQuery UI scripts-->
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>   
<!--END @ jQuery UI scripts-->

<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.contenteditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
//call your function here
//alert("chgdfg");
var col_value=$('.Table').html();
 $.post( "ajax_test.php", { action : 'aftertimeout' ,col_value: col_value})
.done(function( resp ) {
 //console.log(resp);
$('.Table').html(resp);
 //select_reinitilaize();
});
 }, 5000);
</script>

<span style="display:none;" id="select-result"></span>
<span style="display:none;" id="select-for"></span>
<div class="pannel">  
 <div class="text_pannel">
<div class="btn_cont">
<div id="edit" class="unselect chr" title="Toggel Edit">T/E</div>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont">
<div class="chr bold" id="bold" title="Bold">B</div>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont">
<div class="chr italicFont" id="italic" title="Italic">I</div>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont">
<select class="btn selectList" title="Font Size" id="font_size">
<?php for($i=8; $i<=48; $i++){ if($i%2!=0) continue;?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>px"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont" id="font_color_select">
<div class="chr" title="Font Color">A</div>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont" id="field_color_select">
<div class="chr" title="Background Color" style="background-color:#FFCCFF;">A</div>
</div>
<div class="btn_cont">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!--END @ ACTION_PANEL-->
<!--COLOR_BOX-->
<!--END @ COLOR_BOX-->
<div class="Table">
<div id="selectable">
<!--HORIZONTAL_COUNT-->
<div class="Heading">
<div class="Cell first">
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>A</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>B</p>
</div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>C</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>D</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>E</p>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END @ HORIZONTAL_COUNT-->
        <!--ROWS-->
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=1; $i++){ ?>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell first">
                <p><?php echo $i; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p contentEditable="true" id="A<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p contentEditable="true" id="B<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p contentEditable="true" id="C<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p contentEditable="true" id="D<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p contentEditable="true" id="E<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            </div>  <!-- row end here -->
        <?php }?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>  <!-- container -->
```

Comment: ok and where is your code ?

Comment: Showing your can help one assist you. While from what you said it sounds like Ajax refreshes/replace the content but for further assistance place show some code to help us know what is happening